# Kruskal-Wallis test for showing features can discriminate the classes

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm working on a problem for classifying **3** gestures using the EMG signals obtained from muscles.

- Each of the gestures has **6** trials of around **6-7s** duration.
- Each trial is divided into multiple segments of some window length like(150ms with overlapping). The trials are performed by **10** individuals .
- I've extracted **5** features from each segment.
- Each classes/gestures may not have exactly equal number of observations/examples but it would be around 3600.

*This is the background to check if all the assumptions for kw hold or not. I have the feature matrix as X (11000,5) and labels y(11000,1).*

Now I would like to test statistically if each of the 5 features has the ability to discriminate 3 gestures.
Hence for each feature, my understanding is, to use KW test to check that if features coming from 3 gestures are significantly different, i.e. if p-value<0.05 then the features may be able to differentiate the gestures.
I coded in MATLAB for the first feature, like this:

```
[p,tbl,stats]=kruskalwallis(X(:,1),y)
```

My background in statistics is pretty weak, and this is what I've understood so far from reading different articles regarding kw test.

- I would like to know, if my way of thinking for the statistical test to show the discrimination ability of features is correct or not.
- secondly, is the code correct? I have found p=0 for each of the features I've tried. so I'm wondering if there's something wrong.

I'm a non-native speaker so please ignore my grammatical mistakes.
Thank you very much for your valuable feedback.